# How to split a one large FLAC file into many smaller ones?

Tags: linux, command-line

This is not music and there is no cue file.  The FLAC file size can be several GB and I want to break this large FLAC file into many smaller ones based on a file size parameter using a Linux terminal command. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `ffmpeg` with the `-ss` and the `-t` parameters?